# Which visual editor under eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, visual-editor

I have installed eclipse indigo 3.7 the latest version and need a visual editor. Where can i found a visual editor for it?

Comment: What do you mean by visual editor and what us the type of thong it edits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Swing and SWT you can use WindowBuilder (http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/)